# Is any print preview friendly plug-in for sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, printing

Is any print preview friendly plug-in for sharepoint site ?

I used https://www.printfriendly.com/ this but it not work for IE browser..

Comment: I saw your question yesterday and since no one has answered yet, I thought I'd leave a comment.  I often resort to using the 'Print Screen' option to take a screen shot.  Or if you are interested in using List or Document Library information you can use the List>'Export To Excel' button to get a copy of the SP data.  Though I have the feeling that you need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Jquery Print Preview Plugin, it also works for IE:

[jQuery Print Page Options](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-jquery-print-page-options/)